# Slim 3 - Multiple request issue

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am setting up a small Slim 3 application which will be the middleman for processing Web based Stripe payment form. The Slim application will handle the business logic of reaching out to Stripe and conducting the payment, as well as sending the payment data off to some third-party CRM / Applications.

My issue during testing is that when i make a test payment through the StripeJS payment form the slim application is actually logging 3 duplicate requests 1-second apart. Here's what the logging looks like:

```
test@gmail.com  Attempting to make payment  2020-04-27 05:34:39
test@gmail.com  Attempting to make payment  2020-04-27 05:34:40
test@gmail.com  Attempting to make payment  2020-04-27 05:34:41
test@gmail.com  Payment success 2020-04-27 05:34:44
test@gmail.com  Payment success 2020-04-27 05:34:45
test@gmail.com  Payment success 2020-04-27 05:34:47
```

This is all from an individual "payment" using the Stripe Test credentials.

The Slim layout is fairly straightforward in terms of the route passing the request directly to my `StripeController` class. The `StripeController` class ( in development ) will take the values of the request and pass it to the Stripe API to conduct the payment.

The route layout:

`$this->post('/stripe-payment', 'StripeController:stripePayment');`

The controller (stripped to essentials for privacy ):

```
class StripeController extends Controller
{

    private $privateKey;
    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->privateKey = getenv('STRIPE_KEY');
        $this->httpClient = new Client();
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->privateKey);
    }

    // 
    public function stripePayment($request, $response)
    {
        // Get the request body
        $r = (object)$request->getParsedBody();

        // Initial Logging
        $log = new LogController($r->email_address, 'Attempting to make payment');
        $log->saveLog();

        // Attempt to find an existing user
        $user = User::where('email', $r->email_address)->first();

        if($user !== null) {
                // If user exists, use their StripeID
                $invoice = $this->stripeInvoice($r, $user->stripe_id);
                // Log the transaction
                $this->savePayment( $user->id, 'stripe-invoice', $invoice->id, $invoice->amount_paid );
                // Third party application push
                $this->pushUser($r, $invoice->amount_paid);
                // Return with success
                return $response->withRedirect('example.com/payment-success/');

        } else {
            // Same as above, just create a user then push.
        }

    }


    public function stripeInvoice(object $r, string $stripe_id)
    {

        // Try to create the invoice in stripe
        try {

            \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create([
                'customer'  => $stripe_id,
                'amount'    => (int)$r->product,
                'currency'  => 'USD',
                'description'   => $plan_desc
            ]);

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            error_log('STRIPE_INVOICE_EXCEPTION: '.$e->getMessage());

        }

        // Try to charge the customer the invoice we just created
        try {
            $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
                'customer' => $stripe_id
            ]);     
            $_get_invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($invoice->id);
            $_get_invoice->pay();

            $success = 1;
            // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
          } catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
          } catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
          } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
          } catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
          } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Network communication with Stripe failed
          } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            // yourself an email
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
                $error = $e->getMessage();
          }

          if($success != 1) {
            return $response->withRedirect('example.com&error='.$error);
          } else {
              return $_get_invoice;
          }

    }

}
```

Is there anything that Slim is doing in the background, like an origin check, that could be causing the duplication issue ?

Comment: Please add more details to the question, like related pats of you application code which handle these requests.

Comment: I've added the route and controller ( stripped to essentials for privacy ) which handle the actual logic.

Comment: Are there any ideas, or places i can test ?